# I'm getting errors in Xcode after installing Firebase Storage using pods

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uikit, firebase-storage

The errors I'm getting:

[image]

and below is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PingMe Up' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!



# Pods for PingMe Up
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage' 
pod 'Firebase/Core'

# Google Sign In
pod 'GoogleSignIn'

pod 'MessageKit'
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'SDWebImage'


end
```

I have tried everything (cleaning the project, restaring my Mac and restarting Xcode) and nothing is working out for me.

Comment: Switch to SPM if you can it has much better compatibility

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `platform :ios, '11.0'` (or higher) in the Podfile.

Recent versions of Firebase don't support the CocoaPods default of 8.0 and very old versions of the pods are likely being installed.